# Python: how to save a Binary Tree?

Tags: python, persistence, binary-tree

I was wondering how to save a Binary Tree that I have previously created.
Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you so much.

PD: Here there is a link about how to implement a binary tree, I am using this pice od code:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286239-binary-ordered-tree/

Comment: You would like the structure and the data within to be written to the hard disk?

Comment: ... Then again, you could just [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) it.

Comment: @fuggle: Yes, I want to save my tree data in my hard disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy solution: 
- extend the current class to have a `load` and `save` method
- add a unique id to each node
- implement to do a top down parsing and save each node to a xml with a structure like that

```
<node id="mynicelycrafteduniqueid">
    <data>...</data>
    <leftChild>childuniqueId</leftChild>
    <rightChild/> <!-- no right child -->
</node>
```

You're done (if data is easily serialized at least), first node is your tree root.

don't forget fertilizer and your tree will be reborn even more beautiful

Comment: How about to save my xml structures in a txt file? There is something better than save them in a txt file?

Answer (score 5):

There are different types of binary trees with different rules that can help simplify deserialization, but basically, just walk the tree and output each node in order, then to re-create it, read in your file and regenerate the structure.

It may be helpful to include markers for each node that indicate whether it's a leaf node (which then tell you whether or not the next element belongs below or above the current node. Alternately, you may want to have a marker that indicates a NULL node, which might help for nodes with a left but not a right branch, for example.

EG:

```
   A
 B   C
D E    F
```

Could be represented:

```
A B D - - E - - C - F - -
```

Or as:

```
A[B[D,E],C[-,F]]
```

Reminds me of the Computer Science homework I did back in college.

Comment: if the tree is not balanced, this can lead to heavy empty space consumption (2^max_depth_of_tree). Your solution is however good for a balanced tree as the node positionning is implicit while reading, no need to keep tracks of ids

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant at the top about the different types of binary trees. You've got to take your specific usage case into consideration if you want to come up with something efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a small database (such as sqlite3) to have the structure persist.

Example:

```
Node: {nodeId(PK), [leftChildId](FK), [rightChildId](FK)}
leftChildId, rightChildId references Node;
```

Similarly to Bruce's answer, you would implement a `save` / `load` function.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

A binary tree like:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \   \
D   E   F
```

Could be represented as:

```
A B C
B D E
C F
```

Or, more abstractly:

```
<parent-id><separator><child-1-id>(<separator><child-2-id>)?<newline>
```

It depends on how complicated the nodes are. If they are anything other than strings, numbers or booleans, it is probably easier and faster to just pickle the whole tree.

Comment: I like your way, but I need to save the content of every node, not only its id.

Comment: A similar format, maybe: `<parent-content><separator><child-1-id>(<separator><child-2-id>)?<newline>`, where the content string contains the id.